# After upgrading Mac mini to Mountain Lion, the display is not working

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, vga

I had my Mac mini connected to a TV using VGA (with the mini DisplayPort-to-VGA adapter) running fine. After upgrading to Mountain Lion it simply doesn't work anymore.

I wasn't using any software like screen res or so, just pure OS X. Any tips to get that back?

Comment: VGA is not a DB9 connector - it's DB15. (The number is the number of pins.)

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into the machine with your display hooked up with HDMI (just so you can login), then switch over to VGA. Then try CMD + F2 (brightness up) to force detect displays and see if it switches over.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the Mac into the startup manager (hold the option key when you hear the chime as the system is booting). This removes the OS from the picture and lets the firmware drive the monitor and often can assist in knowing if the hardware has failed outright. You may not get a specific resolution in the startup menu, but enough video signal should be present on all video out from the Mac Mini to isolate the cause of the failure.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  In the test you suggested I only get a black screen. It works well with the same display over HDMI but not when using the VGA DB9 connector. You may ask why should I use VGA over HDMI... that's because I borrowed a HDMI cable to test if the thunderbolt is working. The other problem with HDMI is due to sound and shadows in the fonts...

Comment: Seems odd that it would work before the OS version upgrade and not now. I would presume that the hardware would either work with analog VGA or not. I presume you are not using a thunderbolt adapter. Apple does sell a [mini-DP adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/A) which is of course pin compatible with the thunderbolt equipped mini.